# Requested database is not available. Requested database name: 'graph.db'

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

am getting this error message

> {
> "code": "Neo.TransientError.Database.DatabaseUnavailable",
> "message": "Requested database is not available. Requested database name: 'graph.db'."
> }

while sending a request through rest API, with this statement

> {
> "statements" : [ {
> "statement" : "CREATE (n) RETURN id(n)"
> } ]
> }

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you probably don't have a database called `graph.db`. That is the name of the file system directory, not the database. Unless you've set up a database yourself, use `neo4j`, which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

As Nigel said, it'll be because you don't have a graph by that name.
I ran into this issue recently, after upgrading from 3.5.3 to 4.1, and having to figure out some new behaviours (why yes, I *have* been living under a rock).

Read through the server's logs - it reports the database name while it's starting up. If you're using a Docker instance, as I am, `docker logs <instance-id>` is your friend.